# JavaFX addEventListener Memory Leak on Grand Parent

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, javafx-2, javafx

Why would the anonymous inner class not be released here, causing a memory leak? This happens for FX 2.2.1.

```
anchorPane.getParent().getParent().lookup("#grandParentButton").addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            someButtonInsideAnchorPane.requestFocus();
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Why would this below on the other hand be garbage collected?

```
button1InsideAnchorPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            button2InsideAnchorPane.requestFocus();
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is wrong. It's true that "An an inner class always holds a strong ref to its outer class", but then it goes the other way round. Actually, the outer class can't be collected as long as the inner is alive.

The reason for the instance not being collected as its registering as listener. The registrar typically holds a strong reference to the listener, so the instance can't be collected (no idea about FX).

The only explanation for the different behavior is that each object was registered with a different component. One of them has got collected and the other hasn't. No idea why, maybe one of them belonged to a dialog?

Comment: Hi @maaartinus, since the registrar holds a strong reference to the listener, then does it mean that both the inner class and outer class hold a strong reference to each other?

Comment: An anonymous (or other non-static) class instance *always* holds a reference to its enclosing class instance. From your snippet i can't see what's the relationship between the registrar and the enclosing instance.

Comment: The registrar is the outer class here also, right? So when we say it holds a reference to the event listener, that means the outer class also holds a reference to its inner classes. Just confirming.

Answer (score 1):

An  an inner class always holds a strong ref to its outer class and is only gced if the outer one is not referenced any more. Make it a static inner class and you don't have the problem!

Comment: Thanks @tomsontom, I'm still confused though. The second anonymous inner class in my edited question gets released. Can you explain why? Anyway, I read one of your blog posts on memory leak. It's great.